# Is it possible to get documents info like GoLand for VScode in Go?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, plugins, goland

Before I used VScode for Go development and recently I've tried to use GoLand and found out there's a feature in GoLand that it will show the document info for the functions when mousing over, like the pics below.

Is it possible to set up in VSCode?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you install the [go extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=golang.Go) in vscode?

Comment: yes. But it didn't show that. eg, it won't detect HandlerFunc when mousing over and show the documents.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about inclusion of example snippets in the documentation hover, but for regular documentation, that should work in VSCode if you use the go extension.
[image]

If not, I guess there is another issue so the go extension (and the language server) couldn't correctly process the project.